# Upload Usando Javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso aprender a manipular os elementos do html com javascript(eu acho).
Bom tenho esse codigo a baixo, Que faz o upload da imagem, o que quero fazer é que no momento que cliquei no input fiz o upload a imagens já vá para a pasta no servidor.

Esse codigo carrega a imagem e preenche o thumb com a mesma, como não posso usar o botao submit pretendo realizar o javascript pra realizar esse feito.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('div').on('click', '.closeDiv', function() {
        $(this).prev().remove();
        $(this).remove();
        $('#upload-file').val("");
    });
    var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-file");
    //var fileProgress = document.getElementById("progress");
    fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(e) {

        var filesVAR = this.files;
        showThumbnail(filesVAR);
    }, false);

    function showThumbnail(files) {

        var file = files[0];
        var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
        var pDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        //linha pra esconder o input depois do upload
        var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-file").style.display = "none";
        pDiv.setAttribute('class', 'pDiv');
        thumbnail.appendChild(pDiv);
        image.setAttribute('class', 'imgKLIK5');
        pDiv.appendChild(image)

        div.innerHTML = "X";
        div.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            console.log(event.target); // este é o elemento clicado

            //Pra mostrar novamente o input
            fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-file").style.display = "block";
        })


        div.setAttribute('class', 'closeDiv');
        pDiv.appendChild(div)

        image.file = file;
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
            return function(e) {
                aImg.src = e.target.result;
            };
        }(image))
        var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        image.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 40);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Não é um problema perguntar algo simples, problema é não perguntar de forma clara. Poderia [edit] sua questão e explicar melhor o que gostaria de fazer?

Comment: O Javascript em si não é capaz de acessar o disco ou banco de dados. Pra isso é usado alguma outra linguagem, como PHP, Java, etc, ou consumir alguma web service. Se a sua intenção é salvar a imagem em diretório usando só javascript, não vai dar certo.

Comment: @LucasCosta, é possível sim ter javascript executando no back end utilizando NodeJS. O correto seria afirmar que o código executado no client precisa se comunicar com alguma plataforma no servidor para salvar esta imagem, independente da linguagem.

Comment: DiegoGo, você tem algo executando no servidor que deseja salvar o arquivo?

Comment: @Vinicius Com Node sim, mas ele tagou somente Javascript

Comment: bom, o que tenho é uma pagina php, contendo esse script.

Comment: como posso chamar uma pagina php no momento que o thumb foi carregado, na minha cabeça, esse é o momento de salvar a imagem no servidor que faria com o php.

Comment: Você pode disparar o botão submit com $('#submit').trigger();.

Comment: entendi,valeu e obrigado a todos,finalmente encontrei uma comunidade onde posso tirar minhas duvidas :D

Comment: Removi os pedidos de desculpas, isso não torna a pergunta mais clara e como comentado anteriormente o problema não é perguntar algo simples e sim não ser claro no que se pergunta.